# creating an alert that shows when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert

I'm trying to create a function in javascript that gets an alert to show up when you click the submit button. I managed to get the alert to show but it only pops up when you open the page but doesn't work when you click the submit button.
heres the function i created in javascript

```
function orderTics(){
//creates alert
var orderTotal=35;

alert("Your order total is $"+orderTotal);
```

}

I called the function in html like this:

```
<script>
orderTics();
</script>
```

I'm still very much a beginner so any and all tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I recommend taking a look at JS events https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the on submit function like this:

```
$("form.class-name").on("submit", function() {
  alert("I've been submitted.");
});
```

Vanilla JS `onsubmit` event:

```
document.querySelector("form.class-name").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  alert("I've been submitted.");
}, false);
```

You can also use the `event.preventDefault();` method to prevent the form from going to another page, like this:

```
$("form.class-name").on("submit", function(event) {
  even.preventDefault();
  alert("Do stuff");
});
```

Vanilla JS `onsubmit` event with `event.preventDefault();` method:

```
document.querySelector("form.class-name").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("I've been submitted.");
}, false);
```

**NOTE**: when you use the `event.preventDefault();` method the form won't redirect to the target page, *even if* you click the `ok` button in the alert box.

Finally you can just use the `click` event on the submit button, like this:

```
$("button.submit-button-class").on("click", function() {
  alert("I've been clicked!");
});
```

Vanilla JS `onclick` event:

```
document.querySelector("button.submit-button-class").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("I've been clicked!");
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below.

```
$("#FormSelector").on("submit", function() {
   //Your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function like this:

```
<input type="button" value="myButton" onclick="orderTopics();">
```

Comment: Don't use the `onclick` attribute (or any other event attribute for that matter) in your HTML, it's considered to be *bad practice*. For more info check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5871830/5870134